# How to copy every day to another of two destinations?

Tags: cron, copy

How to do this with cron?

- Today: `cp * ~/destination.0`
- Tomorrow: `cp * ~/destination.1`
- Next day: `cp * ~/destination.0`
- Next day: `cp * ~/destination.1`

...and so on.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Yes, I will use rsync, cp was just for the example

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One Liner:

```
0 0 * * * cp /path/to/* /path/to/destination.$(( $(date -d $(date +%F) +%s)/(3600*24) % 2))
```

Explanation:

```
$(( $(date -d 0:00 +%s)/(3600*24) % 2))
```

- will return timestamp in seconds (`+%s`) of today at 0:00 (`-d 0:00`).
- Divided by `(3600*24)` will return number of days from unix epoch.
- `%2` will return 0 or 1 for odd or even days since start of unix epoch.

Comment: `% 2` is simple a modulo operation, which returns 1 if the days number given to it is odd and 0 if it is even.

Comment: `+1` for the solution using the `seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC ` option. On this way you don't have to think about  the 30/31 days/months problem of other attempts here

Comment: @RoVo that's exactly what I've looked for because of the two odd days 31 and 1 ! Very smart!

Comment: True. I updatet the answer.

Answer (score 2):

If it would be OK to write to `~/destination.0` on even dates and `~/destination.1` on odd dates, the following crontab line should work. It starts the backup at midnight (0 min, 0 hour, the two first items on the line),

```
0 0 * * * echo cd dir2copy;dtmp=$(( $(/bin/date '+%d') % 2 ));echo /bin/cp * ~/destination."$dtmp"
```

See this link for an explanation of the crontab syntax,

[Scheduling Tasks with Cron Jobs](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/scheduling-tasks-with-cron-jobs--net-8800)

Test the command part of the line in a terminal window,

```
echo cd dir2copy;dtmp=$(( $(/bin/date '+%d') % 2 ));echo /bin/cp * ~/destination."$dtmp"
```

and when it works, you can replace `cd dir2copy` with `cd to-the-actual-directory-you-want-to-copy`, replace **`~`** with `/home/your-home-directory` and remove the two `echo` words to make it do the real job.

Test it again, and then modify the crontab line. (The environment in crontab is such that you may need explicit full paths to programs, directories and data files.)

---

`/bin/date '+%d'` finds the day of month and `%` is the remaindering operation, that produces a `0` or `1`, which is appended at the end of the command line.

You may prefer `/bin/date '+%j'`, which finds the day of year, for example today, Dec 1, is day `#335`.

Comment: will not alternate between day 365 and 1.

Comment: Yes, you are right @RoVo . I noticed, that you have fixed that, and I will upvote your answer :-) You have spent more effort than I  to make things work exactly according to the specification in the question. It would be OK for me at new year, that the alternation would skip. My computer might be turned off anyway ;-)

Comment: True, but I started with the same problem ... `+%w`: fuck the week has an odd number of days... then `+%d`, then `+%j`... then ... shit I'm fucked ...

Comment: Anyways after a leap year `+%j` will work correctly on new year ^^

Comment: not if the leap year is `%100` :P

Answer (score 2):

I agree with the "run the cronjob daily, switch directories in the script" answers, but I'd do it like this:

```
#!/bin/bash 
# use hidden link
last=$HOME/.last_destination
#
declare -a dirs
dirs[0]="destination.0"
dirs[1]="destination.1"
#
target=
#
# If $last is a link, it points to the last used directory. Otherwise,
# initialize it and use $HOME/destination.0
if [[ -L "$last" ]] ; then
    # get the name of the linked dir
    old="$(stat  --printf="%N" "$last" | cut -d\' -f4)"
    if [[ "$old" == "${dirs[0]}" ]] ; then
        target="${dirs[1]}"
    else
        target="${dirs[0]}"
    fi
else
    # "$last" is not a link - first time initialization
    target="${dirs[0]}"
fi
# now, with $target set, point the $last link at $target, for next time
rm "$last"
ln -s "$target" "$last"
#
# debugging printouts - remove in real life
echo "$target"
ls -l "$last"
```

Answer (score 0):

Run this script daily from cron:

```
#! /bin/sh
set -e
cp * ~/destination.0
mv ~/destination.0 ~/destination.last
mv ~/destination.1 ~/destination.0
mv ~/destination.last ~/destination.0
```

Comment: you never write anything to `~/destination.1`...

Comment: Right, there's a bug in my (untested) script, the last line should rename *.last to *.1 instead of *.0... and in the meantime I've seen better solutions involving modulo 2 computations

Comment: Even than you would every day copy to `destination.1` and have `destination.0` as backup .. but actualy not alternating between two destinations.